Proving $\frac{\tan A}{1-\cot A}+\frac{\cot A}{1-\tan A}=\sec A\csc A+1$
This problem is from S. L. Loney’s 1896 Trigonometry book:
Prove:
$$\frac{\tan A}{1-\cot A}+\frac{\cot A}{1-\tan A}=\sec A\csc A+1$$
Eventually I was able to prove the identity but I want to know if there is a simpler way to prove it.
Here is my proof:
$\frac{\tan A}{1-\cot A}+\frac{\cot A}{1-\tan A}=$
$\Large \frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}{1-\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}}+\frac{\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}}{1-\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}=$
$\Large \frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}{\frac{\sin A-\cos A}{\sin A}}+\frac{\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}}{\frac{\cos A-\sin A}{\cos A}}=$
$\frac{\sin A}{\cos A} \cdot \frac{\sin A}{\sin A-\cos A}+\frac{\cos A}{\sin A} \cdot \frac{\cos A}{\cos A-\sin A}=$
$\frac{\sin^2 A}{\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)}+\frac{\cos^2 A}{\sin A(\cos A-\sin A)}=$
$\frac{1-\cos^2 A}{\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)}+\frac{\sin^2 A-1}{\sin A(\sin A-\cos A)}=$
$\frac{\sin^2 A}{\sin A(\sin A-\cos A)} + \frac{-\cos^2 A}{\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)} + \frac{1}{\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)} + \frac{-1}{\sin A(\sin A-\cos A)}=$
$\frac{\sin A}{\sin A-\cos A} + \frac{-\cos A}{\sin A-\cos A} + \frac{\sin A}{\sin A\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)} + \frac{-\cos A}{\sin A\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)}=$
$\frac{\sin A-\cos A}{\sin A-\cos A} + \frac{\sin A-\cos A}{\sin A\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)}=$
$1 + \csc A\sec A=$
$\sec A\csc A + 1$
Q. E. D.
Edit: I just realized this is a duplicate of the following question:  Trigonometric identity: $\frac {\tan\theta}{1-\cot\theta}+\frac {\cot\theta}{1-\tan\theta} =1+\sec\theta\cdot\csc\theta$

Well, let $u = \tan x$ and then $\frac{u}{1-1/u}+\frac{1/u}{1-u} = \frac{u^3-1}{u(u-1)} = \frac{u^2+u+1}{u} = 1+\frac{u^2+1}{u}$ and the identity follows.

@BrianTung +1 That tangent substitution is very useful!
